# Grails plugin for DocumentDB

Tags: azure, grails, grails-orm, azure-cosmosdb

We are kind of POC phase where we are trying out Azure.

We are using Grails, which has nice support for MongoDb as backend (using GORM), but couldn't find similar support for DocumentDd.

If we choose to go with DocumentDb, our choice would be to have a layer (may be kind of DAO layer) which uses documentDb client library and interacts with DocumentDb. Or we fall back to MongoDb, as its provided Azure.

Any other choices we have with Grails-DocumentDb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use DocumentDB's driver level MongoDB compatibility.

Configure Grails/GORM as if it were talking to MongoDB. Leave the client-side MongoDB drivers in place, but change the connection string to connect to your DocumentDB. See instructions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-protocol-mongodb/).

Comment: You mean to say to you driver we got as 'azure-documentdb' artifact and use connect to documentdb from an layer (usually a doa)? So documentdb gorm plugin doesn't exits?

Comment: Configure Grails/GORM as if it were talking to MongoDB. Leave the client-side MongoDB drivers in place, but change the connection string to connect to your DocumentDB. See instructions here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-protocol-mongodb/

Comment: Good direction, the issue now I am facing is with SSL, should solve it.